# Android NullPointer error Fragment custom class?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Relatively new to Java and Android programming can anybody help as to why I'm getting a `NullPointerException`?

```
 public class DpsFragment extends Fragment {
    Weapon weppy;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            weppy.setMaxdmg(200);
            weppy.setMindmg(100);
            TextView tv= (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
            tv.setText("hello");


            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dpsfrag, container, false);

        }

    public class Weapon {
    private int mindmg;
    private int maxdmg;


    public Weapon(int mindmg, int maxdmg) {
    this.setMindmg(mindmg);
    this.setMaxdmg(maxdmg);
    }


    public int getMindmg() {
    return mindmg;
    }


    public void setMindmg(int mindmg) {
    this.mindmg = mindmg;
    }


    public int getMaxdmg() {
    return maxdmg;
    }


    public void setMaxdmg(int maxdmg) {
    this.maxdmg = maxdmg;
}
}}
```

Very simple code, I know, but I have no idea where I have gone wrong? Thanks for any help .

Comment: In the future, if you're throwing an Exception of any kind, you should post your log rather than only the name of the Exception. Your log will point to a specific line of code where it is being thrown, which ends up being useful for you and anyone trying to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`weppy is null` so NPE ...i think you forgot to initialize it.

it may be `weppy = new Weapon(mindmg,maxdmg);`

**ALSO**

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        weppy = new Weapon(100,200);  <<<<<<See here

        TextView tv= (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
        tv.setText("hello");


        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dpsfrag, container, false);

    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Ouch that was a painfully amateur mistake

Answer (score 0):

Also you can not use getView() inside onCreateView because the view you are accessing has not been created yet. So you should do it like this:

View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dpsfrag, container, false);

TextView tv= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

tv.setText("hello");

return view;